# How to run the same @Scheduled method in Spring Boot in multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a @Scheduled method in my Spring Boot app

```
   @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void taskA() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("A - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

My Spring Application file is as follows:
@SpringBootApplication

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringScheduleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringScheduleApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

I also have a config class set up to establish a thread pool to allow for parallel jobs

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    public static final int NUM_PROCESSING_WORKERS = 10;
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(
            ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_PROCESSING_WORKERS);
    }
}
```

When I run the scheduler, I can clearly see the job is picking up in the multiple thread pools.

```
A - pool-1-thread-7
A - pool-1-thread-3
A - pool-1-thread-9
....
```

Ok..... so here's my problem

What I WANT to do is create multiple instances of `taskA` and have that run in N amount of threads.

I know I can create N amount of methods with the `@Scheduled` annotation performing the same logic, but this is NOT an acceptable solution. This seems very redundant and looks bad, and don't want to copy paste if I add another thread to the pool. I want to be able to say something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SchedulingConfig.NUM_PROCESSING_WORKERS; i++){
  taskA(); // I just want N amount of this tasks existing in parallel.
}
```

I cannot use anything like Quartz Scheduler because I want to be able to continue to use `@Autowired` in my project (I can get this behavior to work in Quartz, but setting up @Autowired is a pain and I would like to work with Spring Schedule annotations as much as possible)

Comment: And what makes you think you cannot use `@Autowired` with Quartz? Also you already have a for loop, what prevents you from using that? Put `@Scheduled` on the method with the for loop, make the `taskA` `@Async` and it will do what you tell it to do (note it has to be in an external class and not in the same class as the `@Scheduled`).

Comment: First off, thank you, the second part of your comment answered my question! If you write as an answer I will accept.

As for Quartz....it's because I have to instantiate new ``JobDetails`` objects with Quartz pointing to my job class. If I autowire in those job classes, Spring does not handle them. Unless I were to pass in all my autowired objects (which doesn't seem good), I don't see a way to feasibly use ``@Autowired`` with Quartz.

Comment: I strongly suggest a read-up on Quartz and how it can be integrated into Spring. As there is special integration and autowiring into job details is certainly possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already wrote the answer yourself. You already have the `for` loop to use. Put the `@Scheduled` on the method with the for-loop, which calls a `taskA` method in an external class, and which has the `@Async` annotation.

```java
@Autowired
private External external

@Scheduled
public void scheduler() {
  for(int i = 0; i < SchedulingConfig.NUM_PROCESSING_WORKERS; i++){
    external.taskA(); // I just want N amount of this tasks existing in parallel.
  }
}
```

```java
public class External {


  @Async
  public void taskA() { ... }

}
```

Another solution is to inject the `AsyncTaskExecutor` into your class that does the scheduling and call `submit` to execute the task.

```
@Autowired
private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

@Scheduled
public void scheduler() {
  for(int i = 0; i < SchedulingConfig.NUM_PROCESSING_WORKERS; i++){
    taskExecutor.submit( () -> taskA());  
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that it is more explicit and that your `taskA` method can be in the same class.